# Why doesn't a regex pattern ending in "." produce a match when using word boundary?

Tags: java, regex, quote

In the following Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String largeText = "abc myphrase. def";
        String phrase = "myphrase.";
        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b"+Pattern.quote(phrase)+"\\b");
        System.out.println("Pattern: "+myPattern);
        Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher( largeText );
        boolean found = false;
        while(myMatcher.find()) {
          System.out.println("Found: "+myMatcher.group());
          found = true;
        }
        if(!found){
            System.out.println("Not found!");
        }
}
```

I get this output:

```
Pattern: \b\Qmyphrase.\E\b
Not found!
```

Please, can someone explain me why the above pattern does not produce a match? I do have a match if I use "myphrase" instead of "myphrase." in the pattern.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no boundary after the `.`  A boundary occurs between a word character and a non-word character.  Since both `.` and `" "` (space) are non-word characters there is no boundary between them.

If you use "myphase" in your pattern you get a match because there is a boundary between the word character `e` and the `.`.

Answer (score 1):

It does't match because dot (`.`) is **not** considered a "word" character, so there **won't** be a word boundary after a literal dot (when the next char is a space).

FYI, "word" characters (which have their own regex `\w`) is equivalent to the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to use \s and not \b ?

Comment: No. I do need '\b' because '\s' would only match whitespaces. Thank you.